# How to match string that may contain hyphen in the where clause?

Tags: sql-server

Suppose that I have a phone number table. In this table, the 'Number' column (nvarchar) may or may not contain hyphen. How do I construct the where clause?

For example, the records may look like this:

> Number | Name
>
> 111    | Peter
>
> 11-22  | Mark
>
> 222-33 | John

If I do

```
SELECT Name FROM table WHERE Number = '22233'
```

I won't find John. And I don't know after which digit the hyphen might appear.

What's the best way to construct the WHERE clause to match record by number?

Comment: `SELECT Name FROM table WHERE REPLACE(Number, '-', '') = '22233' `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT Name FROM table WHERE Replace(Number,'-','') = '22233'
```

Comment: LOL. It's one of those times when I look at the answer and ask myself: how could I not think of this. Thank you.

Comment: @AllenZhang I suspect you were over-thinking it

Comment: @AllenZhang Just a thought.  It may be worth your time to clean/normalize your data.  I store phone numbers and such as just digits and format in the presentation layer if needed.  Cheers

Comment: @Prdp  I tell my wife all the time... It's the curse of intelligence.   She just rolls her eyes.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, this data comes from other components of the application. I don't have control over it, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using `STUFF`, if it always single `-` then use this

```
SELECT Name FROM table 
WHERE Stuff(Number,Charindex('-',Number),1,'') = '22233'
```

John's `Replace` method looks more elegant

Answer (score -1):

Apart from above answer, you can use the `like` and `%` in where clause:

```
SELECT Name FROM table WHERE Number like '%-%'
```

This gives you all those items which have hyphon in their number.

Comment: This matchs 'whatever-whatever'

Comment: I said it matches all numbers with - in them (since the query is on that column)  @AllenZhang why the downvote?

Comment: because your query does NOT match the first record in my example. The number MAY or MAY NOT contain a hyphen. But thanks for asking, I really think SO should force down voters to leave a reason.